# PHP execute Python script: provide input on prompt, read multiple outputs

Tags: php, python

I have a `Python` script that prompts the user for inputs.

```
input = raw_input("Enter input file: ")
model = raw_input("Enter model file: ")
```

While I can use the following `PHP` command to execute the script, how can I provide inputs when prompted?

```
$output = shell_exec("python script.py");
```

Also, like `shell_exec()`, I want to return all lines of output, not just the first/last line printed.

**Solution that worked:**

```
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"), 
    1 => array("pipe", "w")
);  
$process = proc_open('python files/script.py', $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, null); // run script.py
if (is_resource($process)) {
    fwrite($pipes[0], "files/input.txt\n"); // input 1      
    fwrite($pipes[0], "files/model.txt\n"); // input 2

    fclose($pipes[0]); // has to be closed before reading output!
    $output = "";
    while (!feof($pipes[1])) {
        $output .= fgets($pipes[1]);
    }
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    proc_close($process);  // stop script.py
    echo ($output);
}
```

**Reference:** [Piping between processes in PHP](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/16/1/9/piping-between-processes)

Answer (score 0):

I propose to concatenate all output lines with a `delimiter` character like `$` and decompose it on the PHP side using `explode` function to have an array.